# Cannot deploy SSRS report

Tags: .net, reporting-services

When i want to deploy a SSRS report from visual studio to a server in my Lan network i get this error.

```
Could not connect to the report server http://10.42.7.14/ReportServer_MSDEV.
Verify that the TargetServerURL is valid and that you have the correct permissions to connect to the report server.

At Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.ListItemTypes()
at ReportServiceClient2010.CheckAuthenticated()
at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.DetectEndpointAndAuthenticate(String url, ICredentials credentials, String& authCookieName, Cookie& authCookie, EndpointType& endpointType)
at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.DetectEndpointAndAuthenticate(String url, ConnectionProperties& connectionProperties)
at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.GetCredentials(String url, CancelFlag cancelFlag)
at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportProjectDeployer.PrepareDeploy()
```

Comment: You should be able to place that exact address in a browser and get back a 'folder listing' from the root of the SSRS server.  Does it work with the address you are trying to deploy to?

Comment: Yes i can access the adress with the browser

Answer (score 0):

You might be giving wrong credentials, whenever you deploy your SSRS report to reporting server it asks username and password, the above mentioned error in your post shows that you might be giving wrong credentials.

Username and password must be correct to have access to your reporting server.

Answer (score 0):

It is far easier IMHO to add reports **FROM** the report server!

Use the upload file option.[image: Upload File]

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things you could check:
Check the URL you are using is correct, you can check this by going to SQL Server Reporting Services (I believe you need admin on the host you are accessing this from) and go to the web service url section:
SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration Manager > Web Service URL > Report Server Web URL

Check that you can connect to the SSRS Server via browser and that you can navigate to the location you are going to upload the report to. You can manually add the report as BIDeveloper pointed out. If this fails you may have insufficient permissions for the account you are using to upload reports.

You will need an account that has either Content Manager/System Administrator SSRS roles to grant your account item level permissions to view/edit/manage content as stated here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx